# Is $y=-x$ an equivalence relation in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: relations

Setting ₩Gamma $f = (x, f(x))$ which is in $(X*Y)$ s.t. $x$ is an element of $X$) and $f:= X to Y$

We know this is a graph,

but how to show this is an equivalence relation

Reflexive $f(x)=f(x)$  so $x$~$x$

And symmetric, transitive conditions must be satisfied. But $f(x)=-x$ is bijection so there are no other element which satisfy $f(x)=f(y)$ if $x=y$

How to prove symmetricity and transitivity?

Comment: No, x = -y is not an equivalence relation; it is an equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going wrong already for reflexitivy.

Your formatting is a bit wonky, but it looks like your definition is

$$ {\sim} = \{(x,f(x)) \mid x\in X\} $$

for some fixed function $f$. This means that $a\sim b$ if *and only if* there is some $x$ such that $a=x$ and $b=f(x)$. Or, cutting out the middleman, $a\sim b$ if and only if $b=f(a)$.

For reflexivity we then ask: Is it always the case that $x\sim x$? Or, by the definition we've just unfolded: Is it always the case that $x=f(x)$ -- no matter what $x$ is?

In your attempt you've somehow ended up writing $f(x)=f(x)$ instead of $x=f(x)$.

So when $f$ is negation, the relation is not reflexive. Namely, if $x=42$, then $x=f(x)$ does not hold: $42\ne -42$.

Comment: You did not use y = -x.  Nay, this guessing what the question is and answering your guess is of no service.  What is needed in this case, is tutoring mathematical coherence.

Comment: @WilliamElliot: Feel free to write another answer that you think will be more likely to help the OP.